# Why not showing all fields data of drupal 7 when i'm using node resources for client

Tags: drupal-7

I'm new in drupal7. I have made [a website](http://mantis.vu.edu.pk/nextdoor)  in which I make a content type like property. Now i am making a IOS App for this site. I'm using a services module and rest server for fetching data in json format from drupal.

In IOS when fetching data of node of property content type with this [link](http://mantis.vu.edu.pk/nextdoor/note/node.json) . it's return all published nodes but with some specific fields like nid , title, uid , comment , sticky if i want fetch all fields of content type node id required. But i want all my required fields with out passing node id.

How iss it possible. Can i fetch my all fields in JSON format using above link or without passing node id?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you know views module. You can Install the views module "Views Datasource":

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource

With it, you can export custom queries in JSON or XML format.